# How to add a custom dropdown category attribute in the admin and front end? For magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, attributes, frontend, dropdown-attribute

I have followed a few tutorials on the net and ran a few searches on SO. What I want to do is create a custom select box on the admin category section. So users can select an option yes or no.

I followed a tutorial and so far came with this, but nothing appears once I delete my var/cache folder. This is my setup.

```
/app/code/local/Adept_Catlanding/sql/adept_catlanding_setup/mysql4-install-0.3.0.php
/app/code/local/Adept_Catlanding/etc/config.xml
/app/etc/modules/Adept_Catlanding.xml
```

These are the code files:

**Adept_Catlanding.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Adept_Catlanding>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Adept_Catlanding>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**mysql4-install-0.3.0.php**

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

/**
 * This is an entity associated with catalog_category
 * @var  integer
 */
$entityTypeId     = $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_category');

/**
 * Use the default attribute set for catalog_category -- this refers to the table `eav_attribute_set`
 * In my case, it's 3, but this function should automatically get that for you.
 * @var integer
 */
$attributeSetId   = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);

/**
 * This determines what group (tab) that the field will be placed. "General Information" 
 * is the default tab, and I'm okay with this, but see `eav_attribute_group` for other
 * groups
 * @var integer
 */
$attributeGroupId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

/**
 * Let's set up our attribute, customize the type as needed (e.g. int, varchar, decimal)
 * Note where I've used `internal_title` and change to your variable.
 */
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'internal_title',  array(
    'type'     => 'varchar', /* Type - see eav_entity_* for the different types */
    'label'    => 'Enable Brand link?', /* Your label */
    'input'    => 'select', /* This refers to the type of form field should display*/
    'global'   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'           => TRUE,
    'required'          => FALSE,
    'user_defined'      => FALSE,
    'default'           => ''
));

/**
 * Now, add the attribute to the proper attribute group - again, replace the variable title
 * with yours.
 */
$installer->addAttributeToGroup(
    $entityTypeId,
    $attributeSetId,
    $attributeGroupId,
    'brandislinked',
    '2' /* Refers to the sort order of fields - see `eav_entity_attribute` for reference on the location of other fields.  I want this right below the active field, so 2 works for me.*/
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Adept_Catlanding>
            <!-- Make sure that the version number matches the filename on your install script! -->
            <version>0.3.0</version>
        </Adept_Catlanding>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <adept_catlanding_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Adept_Catlanding</module>
                    <!-- This next line is absolutely critical so that we call the appropriate setup class --> 
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_setup</use>
                    </connection>
                </setup>
            </adept_catlanding_setup>
            <adept_catlanding_setup_write>
              <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
              </connection>
            </adept_catlanding_setup_write>
            <adept_catlanding_setup_read>
              <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
              </connection>
            </adept_catlanding_setup_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

I am using Magento 1.9 CE for the development environment and EE for the live environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this in installer script,

```
<?php 
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
//First Remove the custom attribute this after install again
$nameAttribute  = array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'label'=> 'Enable Brand link',
    'input' => 'select',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'default' => '',
    'group' => "General Information"
);
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'internal_title', $nameAttribute); 
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: It still is not appearing.

Answer (score 1):

Please add the attribute and add the option as model.

```
<?php
 $this->startSetup();
 $this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'custom_dropdown',     array(
'group'         => 'General Information',
'input'         => 'select',
'type'          => 'text',
'label'         => 'Custom Dropdown',
'backend'       => '',
'visible'       => true,
'required'      => false,
'visible_on_front' => true,
'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
'source' => 'customfeaturedattribute/source_custom',
));
 $this->endSetup();
```

Inside the model file enter

```
<?php

class Addpeople_CustomFeaturedAttribute_Model_Source_Custom extends  Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract
{
public function getAllOptions()
{
    $options = array(
        1 => 'One',
        2 => 'Two',
        3 => 'Three'
    );

    return $options;
}
}
```

Please refer my tutorial for the file structure and step by step explanation
http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/how-to-add-custom-dropdown-attribute-to-magento-category-section/